# Generating affine pentagon from any pentagon

Tags: geometry

Just as we can generate an affine-regular quadrilateral from any quadrilateral(the Varignon parallelogram), is there a way to generate an affine-regular pentagon from any given arbitrary pentagon? (Eventually using a process of averaging similar to the quadrilateral case, not using something like Petr-Douglas-Neumann theorem).

An affine-regular n-gon is the image of an regular n-gon under an arbitrary affine transformation. In particular, a pentagon ABCDE is affine iff $AB||CE,BC||AD,CD||EB,DE||AC,EA||BD$.

Comment: Sorry, what are an "affine quadrilateral" and an "affine pentagon", and how do they differ from an arbitrary quadrilateral and pentagon?

Comment: What do you mean by “generate”? Is this specific about [midpoint polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_polygon), i.e. are you asking whether the midpoint polygon of a generic pentagon will be affine-regular? If this is not the question, what constraints do you impose against e.g. “inscribe some circle, then inscribe regular pentagon into that”? Some uniqueness conditions? Some continuity to avoid arbitrary choices of unique results?